# custom actions are not visible

Tags: 2010, ribbon, custom-actions

I have a custom action for the menu, but I can not see it.
1. I am site collection admin
2. I checked the feature and its there
3. I checked the package and is there
4. I checked the 14 hive and updated xml files are there when I update the solution.

What else should I check?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction Id="SiteActionsToolbar" Rights="ApplyStyleSheets" GroupId="SiteActions" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"  Sequence="1010" Title="Create New Workspace" Description="Create a new xx Workspace" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/NewContentPageHH.png">
        <UrlAction Url="_layouts/xx/CreateWorkspace.aspx"/>
    </CustomAction>
    <CustomAction Id="SiteActionsToolbar" Rights="ApplyStyleSheets" GroupId="SiteActions" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" Sequence="1020" Title="xx Access Request List"  Description="View Access Requests for xx Teams Workspaces" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/Permissions32.png">
        <UrlAction Url="Lists/RequestAccessHome/AllItems.aspx"/>
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Hi super I try your custom action and it's works fine.any error u found in deployment?

Comment: when I execute the update-sp solution it works fine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you check your URLs. These URLs are relative to the current address, so in your CAs if you're inside a list, for example, your URL action won't go to the expected URL.

In other words, if your current URL is http://site/Lists/Calendar.aspx, your first CA will action to http://site/Lists/Calendar.aspx_layouts/xx/CreateWorkspace.aspx, which probaly isn't what you want, and will ruin any permission checking you may want to do too.

Instead, prepend ~site or ~sitecollection to the from of your URL action:

```
<UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/xx/CreateWorkspace.aspx"/>
```

.b

Comment: what I did is to enable-sp feature with the -force parameter and then it worked.  Apparently something messed up in another deployment, but after doing force it works again.